# Applying a structure-preserving UDF to a column of structs in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have the schema

```
 |-- count: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day4: long (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
```

and I would like to do a transformation on the data such that the structure of `count` is preserved, i.e., it still has four fields (day1, day2,...) of type `long`. The transformation I'd like to do is add the value of the `day1` field to the other fields. My idea was to use a UDF but I'm not sure how 1) to have the UDF return a struct with the same structure and 2) how, within the UDF, to access the fields of the struct that it's transforming (in order to get the value of the `day1` field). The logic for the UDF should be simple, something like

```
s : StructType => StructType(s.day1, s.day1+s.day2, s.day1+s.day3,s.day1+s.day4)
```

but I don't know how to get the correct types/preserve the field names of the original structure. I'm very new to Spark so any guidance is much appreciated.

Also, I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me to the right documentation for this type of thing. I feel that this type of simple transformation should be very simple but I was reading the Spark docs and it wasn't clear to me how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `udf`. Just `select` / `withColumn`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

df.withColumn("count", 
  struct(
    $"count.day1".alias("day1"),
    ($"count.day1" + $"count.day2").alias("day2"), 
    ($"count.day1" + $"count.day3").alias("day3"),
    ($"count.day1" + $"count.day4").alias("day4")))
```